# wso2 api manager :-- Wait until Qpid server starts on port

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

While starting WSO2 API Manager with default settings and h2 database. It is unable to start. The error is below:--

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-06-18 05:44:07,794] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.andes.internal.QpidServiceComponent} -  Wait until Qpid server starts on port 5672 {org.wso2.carbon.andes.internal.QpidServiceComponent}
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:204)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
        at org.wso2.carbon.andes.internal.QpidServiceComponent.startAMQPServer(QpidServiceComponent.java:488)
        at org.wso2.carbon.andes.internal.QpidServiceComponent.startAndesBroker(QpidServiceComponent.java:439)
        at org.wso2.carbon.andes.internal.QpidServiceComponent.activate(QpidServiceComponent.java:165)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
```

Note:-- Firewald service is disabled out here.

Comment: Which version of APIM are you using?

Comment: wso2 api manager 2.1.0,                                                                                       
OS : RHEL 7.4 64 bit,                                                                                          java -version
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: Initial question: Have you checked if another process is listening in 5672 port?

Comment: there is no process running on 5672, also I have tried with "offset 2". Got same error.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if any other processes are occupying 5672. (If so kill that process or offset the WSO2 ports by n.) Then, let it try connecting for 20 minutes. If not, check the CPU utilization at the time. Similar issue got resolved by increasing the number of CPU cores.

Answer (score 0):

Try turn offing the firewall

```
sudo ufw disable
```